# flutter_custom_tabs: ^1.1.1 issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use this package but got some errors when i run my app (flutter run)

Errors: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSq7U.png)

i added this line into build.gradle

```
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
       repositories {
        google() // Add this line to specify the Google Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0' // Updated Gradle version
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

how i used it:

```
  flutter_custom_tabs: ^1.1.1
```

```
import 'package:flutter_custom_tabs/flutter_custom_tabs.dart';
```

```
 void _launchURL(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await launch(
        'https://flutter.dev',
        customTabsOption: CustomTabsOption(
          toolbarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          showPageTitle: true,
          extraCustomTabs: const <String>[
            // ref. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox
            'org.mozilla.firefox',
            // ref. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.emmx
            'com.microsoft.emmx',
          ],
        ),
        safariVCOption: SafariViewControllerOption(
          preferredBarTintColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          preferredControlTintColor: Colors.white,
          barCollapsingEnabled: true,
          entersReaderIfAvailable: false,
          dismissButtonStyle: SafariViewControllerDismissButtonStyle.close,
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      // An exception is thrown if browser app is not installed on Android device.
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
```